# centering a div and/or ul in css

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a problem with a ul . i could center it but now i cant.
here's my code

```css
.wrapper{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
    float: left;
}
.nav{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
   
}

ul li{
    text-align:center;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<ul class="nav">
 <li><a href='#'><div class="wrap"><img src="img/13.jpg" alt="" width="200"    height="200" class="w1"></div></a></li>
 <li><a href='#'><div class="wrap"><img src="img/11.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200" class="w2"></div></a></li>
 <li><a href='#'><div class="wrap"><img src="img/12.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200" class="w3"></div></a></li>
 <li><a href='#'><div class="wrap"><img src="img/14.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200" class="w4"></div></a></li>           
</ul>
  
            </div>
```

i tried to use only a ul but i decided to use a wrapper element but still i dont know what to do.
i want to center it vertically and horizontally .

Comment: CSS: centering vertically? piece of cake. Centering horizontally? lol no

Comment: @JSelser  ik lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes we added too many CSS and get lost.
Use a wrapper is the right direction, just use `flexbox` to center all child.

to center vertically and horizontally, first you need to have a container that at least as big as the screen view size, otherwise, your element will be on the top of the page because the container is too small. so use:

```
min-width: 100vw;
min-height: 100vh;
```

As you have more item the width and height will grow but the item will still be centered by using `flexbox`:

```
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

To list all `li` in one row using:

```
.nav>li {
  float: left;
}
```

remove the default padding margin from HTML body:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: green;
}

.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav>li {
  float: left;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <div class="wrap"><img src="img/13.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200" class="w1"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <div class="wrap"><img src="img/13.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200" class="w1"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#'>
        <div class="wrap"><img src="img/13.jpg" alt="" width="200" height="200" class="w1"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but here is the problem its now centered but the navbar is  vertical and i dont want that i want it to be horizontal

Comment: @majidmashmool ok check the updated answer. I will explain later

Comment: @majidmashmool happy to help, I will add some explanations

Comment: very helpful thank you so much . i want to ask something, when i click on anywhere on the page the nav turns into blue like i selected them it just happened in firefox . what is the cause you think ?

Comment: @majidmashmool not sure what happened, try to add some background-color to different block to debug, also try to do a hard reload. sometime your page may have old style cached so hard reload might help.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to make use of the existing code just replace the height and width to 100px instead of 200px.

Comment: or else please tell which layout do you want, by showing any figure.

Comment: which height and width do you mean?

Comment: of the img tag.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to centering any  div then use this code that i have just tried to create a simple login page.

```
    #divLogin
    {
        width: 450px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 20%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

Comment: it worked somehow but also messed up my whole page ! as you know centering elements depends on the other thing in your code i belive